# How To Change The Rows And Column In SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, .net

SQL TABLE RESULT LIKE THIS

```
InvoiceId Tax1 Tax1value  Tax2  Tax2Value Tax3   Tax3Value
10         GST   2.0       PST    2.8      GRT     3.1
```

Query To GET Above Result

```
SELECT InvoiceId,Tax1,Tax1value,Tax2,Tax2value,Tax3,Tax3Value
FROM Invoice
WHERE InvoicId=10
```

Now I Need Table OutPut Like Blow For Same Invoice Table

```
GST    PST    GRT
2.0    2.8    3.1
```

How To GET Result Like This

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
SELECT Tax1value AS GST, Tax2value AS PST, Tax3Value AS GRT
FROM Invoice
WHERE InvoiceId = 10
```

From http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-as.html

> The keyword AS is used to assign an alias to the column or a table.

Result will be;

```
| GST | PST | GRT |
|-----|-----|-----|
|   2 |   3 |   3 |
```

Here a <kbd>[`SQL Fiddle DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04137/2)</kbd>.

Comment: Gonul i Dont'need Static Asign Value Like Tax1value AS GST . i need Dynamic.

Comment: @Gurunathan You want to change column names when your sql query work?

Comment: Gonul I Need Run This Query Condition Like  WHERE InvoiceId=56

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808189/setting-column-values-as-column-names-in-the-sql-query-result), maybe could be useful for you.

Applied to your case would be something like this:

```
SELECT
  invoiceid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (tax1= 'GST') THEN tax1value ELSE NULL END) AS GST,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (tax2 = 'PST') THEN tax2value ELSE NULL END) AS PST,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (tax3 = 'GRT') THEN tax3value ELSE NULL END) AS GRT
FROM
  invoice
GROUP BY invoiceid
ORDER BY invoiceid
```

Comment: GST,PST,GRT or Dynamic Values Then How I can Use It..?

Comment: You must know those values before. Paraphrasing the answer's question of the link, if the number of possible values is unknown you need to build the SQL statement dynamically in a loop. That`s your question?