# Turning arbitrarily many rows into columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table in Postgres that was designed to capture information in unstructured form and rebuild it. I need to re-apply some structure when exporting data from that table and am struggling.

Currently, I have a table of the form:

```
lbl |   name     |  value
----|------------|--------
1   | num        |       1
1   | colour     |   "Red"
1   | percentage |    25.0
2   | num        |       2
2   | colour     | "Green"
2   | percentage |    50.0
3   | num        |       3
3   | colour     |  "Blue"
3   | percentage |    75.0
```

And I need to generate a table in this form:

```
lbl | num |  colour | percentage
----|-----|---------|------------
1   | 1   | "Red"   |   25.0
2   | 2   | "Green" |   50.0
3   | 3   | "Blue"  |   75.0
```

I have built this query:

```
SELECT lbl, 
   max(case when name = 'num' then value else '-' end) num,
   max(case when name = 'colour' then value else '-' end) colour,
   max(case when name = 'percentage' then value else '-' end) percentage
FROM example_table
GROUP BY lbl
```

The query works but I need to expand it to include an arbitrary number of potential values for name. I have investigated crossfunc but was unable to get it to work as I intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've set up an sqlfiddle here to help kick things off: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d3133/6/0

edit: I can use PL/pgSQL also if that makes it possible.

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic SQL here.

Comment: "*include an arbitrary number of potential values for name*" that's not possible in plain SQL. The number of columns of a query must be know to the database _before_ running the query.

Comment: ah, ok. If I have access to use plsql could that work?

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query?rq=1

Comment: I think a couple of links deep there, I might be able to find an answer. Most of them don't seem to deal with the case that I have arbitrarily many 'name' values.

For a known value, even a large one, it seems easy but in my case I don't know ahead of time what the values are.

Comment: [column values as column names in thepsql query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40473523/593144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with pivot tables in Postgres (and other RDBMS) is that the structure (number and names of columns) of a query result cannot vary depending on the selected data. One of the possible solutions is to dynamically create a view, which structure is defined by the data. The example function creates a view based on the table `example_table`:

```
create or replace function create_pivot_view()
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    list text;
begin
    select string_agg(format('jdata->>%1$L "%1$s"', name), ', ')
    from (
        select distinct name
        from example_table
        ) sub
    into list;

    execute format($f$
        drop view if exists example_pivot_view;
        create view example_pivot_view as
        select lbl, %s
        from (
            select lbl, json_object_agg(name, value) jdata
            from example_table
            group by 1
            order by 1
            ) sub
        $f$, list);
end $$;
```

Use the function after the table is modified (maybe in a trigger) and query the created view:

```
select create_pivot_view();

select *
from example_pivot_view;

 lbl | num | colour | percentage 
-----+-----+--------+------------
   1 | 1   | Red    | 25.0
   2 | 2   | Green  | 50.0
   3 | 3   | Blue   | 75.0
(3 rows)
```

[Test it in db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=52ad2d4b8486014f550d4f1a68779d4f)

Note, that it's necessary to recreate a view (call the function) only after a new name is added to the table (or some name is removed from it). If the set of distinct names doesn't change you can query the view without recreating it. If the set is modified frequently creating a temporary view would be a better option.

You may be also interested in [Flatten aggregated key/value pairs from a JSONB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179515/1995738)

Comment: What about concurrency? Change `create view example_pivot_view as` to `declare example_pivot_view cursor for` and `select * from example_pivot_view;` to `fetch all from example_pivot_view;` - it will be much safer.

Comment: The cursor is a good idea. I don't propose this mainly because general knowledge of the correct use of cursors is minimal, the solution is difficult enough for the average reader.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. I tested first with the view and secondly with the cursor and both worked. There are some other components of our tools that work with cursors so I am not entirely unfamiliar with them.

Comment: As a follow up question, is it possible to join the results of the `FETCH ALL FROM example_pivot_cursor;` with another result set? If not, I might need to stick with the view example.

Comment: There is no simple way of joining rows fetched from a cursor with other data like in regular select.

Comment: @George Never payed attention to it but it is possible to `create temporary view` - IMO it is the best solution.

Comment: @Abelisto - thanks, I've added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select
tab.ibl,
t1_num.value as "num",
t2_color.value as "colour",
t3_perc.value as "percentage"
from
(
    select distinct ibl from your_table order by tab.ibl desc
) tab
left join your_table t1_num on t1_num.ibl = tab.ibl and t1_num.name = 'num'
left join your_table t2_color on t2_color.ibl = tab.ibl and t2_color.name = 'colour'
left join your_table t3_perc on t3_perc.ibl = tab.ibl and t3_perc.name = 'percentage'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this still requires knowing what the potential values of the name column are ahead of time.