# Arranging the data on the basis of column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.4

I have a table which has the below structure.

```
+ ----------------------+--------------+--------+
| timeStamp             | value        | type   |
+ ----------------------+--------------+--------+
| '2010-01-14 00:00:00' | '11787.3743' | 'mean' |
| '2018-04-03 14:19:21' | '9.9908'     | 'std'  |
| '2018-04-03 14:19:21' | '11787.3743' | 'min'  |
+ ----------------------+--------------+--------+
```

Now i want to write a select query where i can fetch the data on the basis of type.

```
+ ----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| timeStamp             | mean_type    | min_type    | std_type |
+ ----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| '2010-01-14 00:00:00' | '11787.3743' |             |          |
| '2018-04-03 14:19:21' |              |             | '9.9908' |
| '2018-04-03 14:19:21' |              | '11787.3743 |          |
+ ----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

Please help me how can i do this in postgres DB by writing a query.I also want to get the data at the interval of 10 minutes only.

Comment: Exactly which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't understand the result shown. What makes you pick these three values?

Comment: @Aureate : I am using postgres DB.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Can you understand the result now ?

Comment: @iftekhariftekhar Since postgres does not support PIVOT function I am deleting my answer but you can use CROSSTAB function to get the desired output.

Comment: @iftekhar iftekhar: Yes, now it's just another way to display the three records. klin's query shows how to achieve this.

Comment: @Aureate - note that the OP does not seem to want PIVOT anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Use `CASE ... WHEN ...`:

```
with my_table(timestamp, value, type) as (
values
    ('2010-01-14 00:00:00', 11787.3743, 'mean'),
    ('2018-04-03 14:19:21', 9.9908, 'std'),
    ('2018-04-03 14:19:21', 11787.3743, 'min')
)
select 
    timestamp,
    case type when 'mean' then value end as mean_type,
    case type when 'min' then value end as min_type,
    case type when 'std' then value end as std_type
from my_table;

      timestamp      | mean_type  |  min_type  | std_type 
---------------------+------------+------------+----------
 2010-01-14 00:00:00 | 11787.3743 |            |         
 2018-04-03 14:19:21 |            |            |   9.9908
 2018-04-03 14:19:21 |            | 11787.3743 |         
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the output the OP needs, does it? -1 since this solution is not helpful.

Comment: @klin : How can i make the column (mean_type/min_type/std_type) dynamic and use concat like ----  case mc.type when 'mean' then value end as concat(s.type,'-',s.height,'-',s.boom_orientation_angle,'-',s.suffix,'mean'),

Comment: i am not able to use concat here..Please help!

Comment: It's not possible in a simple way, as the structure of the result (the number, names and types of columns) have to be strictly defined in the query. You can use dynamic sql to create a view, like in this answer: [Turning arbitrarily many rows into columns in PostgreSQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547713/1995738)

Comment: @mathguy - Would you be so kind as not vote on answers you don't understand?

Comment: @AdamPiotrowski - I understood the answer perfectly well. It seems I didn't understand the question too well. I thought the OP needed to pivot the input data (I even wrote an answer in that sense). When klin pointed out his answer did output what the OP wanted I looked at the *question* again and got it (at the time, the desired output wasn't as clear as it is now. after heavy editing) - but by then it was too late to retract my downvote. I did delete my answer though. Apologies to klin!

Comment: @klin : Any Idea how can i only get the data at the interval of 10 minutes only?

Comment: @iftekhariftekhar - Adapt Gordon's answer on your another question.

Comment: @mathguy - Never mind, the original question wasn't clear indeed. I've updated the answer, you can correct your voting if you want.