# Postgresql - Use selected column from one table as json select statements

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZXz9hJRzpiEmDr7V8PXEG/0

Postgresql 10.x

Consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes (
    attr TEXT
);

INSERT INTO attributes VALUES('sth1');
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES('sth2');

CREATE TABLE items (
    name TEXT,
    custom JSONB
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES ('A', '{"sth1": "Hello"}');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('B', '{"sth1": "Hello", "sth2": "Okay"}');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('C', '{"sthNOT": "Hello", "sth2": "Okay"}');
```

My goal is to only query the columns from the `attributes` table as Json keys in the `ìtems.custom` column - so the query always returns the same set of keys.

When I know the columns I would do just:

```
SELECT name, custom->>'sth1', custom->>'sth2' FROM items;
```

I would like to make this query "dynamic" - so there can be arbitrary key definition in the `attributes` table.

It would also be acceptable for me, to create a new Json object in the query - only containing the keys defined in the `attributes` table and the corresponding values from the `items.custom` column. So merging one Json object created from the `attributes` with the `items.custom` data would be an option.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function to dynamically format and execute a suitable query. The function returns rows with `name` and a jsonb object `data`:

```
create or replace function select_from_items()
returns table(name text, data jsonb) language plpgsql as $$
declare
    cols text;
begin
    select string_agg(format('%1$L, custom->>%1$L', attr), ', ')
    from attributes
    into cols;

    return query execute format('
        select name, jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object(%s)) 
        from items', cols);
end $$;

select * from select_from_items();

 name |               data                
------+-----------------------------------
 A    | {"sth1": "Hello"}
 B    | {"sth1": "Hello", "sth2": "Okay"}
 C    | {"sth2": "Okay"}
(3 rows)
```

It is therefore your second option. The first one assumes creating a kind of pivot table and needs more complicated techniques, see e.g.

- [Turning arbitrarily many rows into columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547713/1995738) or
- [Postgres: Flatten aggregated key/value pairs from a JSONB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179515/1995738)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! Very much appreciated.