# How to map a value in table-A to a column in table-B in postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, postgresql

I have table-A as below ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJyeG.png)):

```
+ ---------------------------- + -------------------------- + ------------- + --------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------------------------- +
| id                           | property_name              | property_type | old_value | new_value  | flexfield | audit_entry_id               |
+ ---------------------------- + -------------------------- + ------------- + --------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------------------------- +
| adtc681050702060b5d7900029d3 | Assigned to                | String        |           | nxp29999   | f         | adte18d46dd91385221b300029ce |
| adtc59c67bc37a132c19a00029d2 | PT Status                  | String        | New       | Analyzing  | f         | adte18d46dd91385221b300029ce |
| adtc49bb8f9acbf7fd9fb00029d1 | Due Date                   | String        |           | 2016-09-27 | f         | adte18d46dd91385221b300029ce |
| adtc3b186528380a5e8fc00029d0 | To be solved in SW release | String        |           | 10.1       | f         | adte18d46dd91385221b300029ce |
+ ---------------------------- + -------------------------- + ------------- + --------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------------------------- +
```

Table-b - here i have each property in above table as an column.
For example : "Assigned to" is a column name in table b and simllarly others

```
+ ----------- + --------- + -------- + -------------------------- +
| Assigned To | PT Status | Due Date | To be solved in SW release |
+ ----------- + --------- + -------- + -------------------------- +
```

How do i map them ??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808189/setting-column-values-as-column-names-in-the-sql-query-result

Comment: @SubratSahoo You say that each property in Table A is a column in Table B and that you want to map values from one to the other. What values are you trying to map? Can you give us an example of your expected output?

Comment: Is this the full schema of these tables, and is the column audit_entry_id also in Table B? That value is the same in table A which may indicate that the values in your example for table A are all for the same entity.

Comment: @cornuz this helps. Thanks