# Loop through temp table and use column values as column names in a select statement in another query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

I am creating a temp table and want to loop through the rows in that temp table and then use the values as column names in a select statement in another query.

**Temp Table**

```
Reviewer    |  Status
---------------------------
Reviewer1   |  Under Review
Reviewer2   |  Approved
Reviewer3   |  Denied
Reviewer4   |  Under Review
```

**Desired Result**

```
Reviewer1     |  Reviewer2     |  Reviewer3     |  Reviewer4
------------------------------------------------------------
Under Review  |  Approved      |  Denied        |  Under Review
```

I've followed this example:  [Setting column values as column names in the SQL query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808189/setting-column-values-as-column-names-in-the-sql-query-result)
and can get it to work with a pre-defined numbers of rows/values in the temp table, but I will have an undefined number of Reviewers and I can't get the dynamic select version to work because SQL does not have a Group_Contact function.

I've been stuck on this awhile and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Assuming by the article you linked to you are using MySQL?

Comment: I am using microsoft sql server 2016,  Thanks!

Comment: One way to do it would be with the use of `PIVOT` through dynamic SQL.

Comment: As BJones commented, `PIVOT`... my first instinct when requirement involves transpose ("columns becomes rows" or vice versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this script will help. As I mentioned above it's using `PIVOT` with dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Review (Reviewer VARCHAR(100), Status VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO Review
VALUES ('Reviewer1','Under Review'),
       ('Reviewer2','Approved'),
       ('Reviewer3','Denied'),
       ('Reviewer4','Under Review'),
       ('Reviewer5','Denied'),
       ('Reviewer6','Under Review');

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Name)
  FROM (SELECT p.Reviewer AS Name
        FROM Review AS p
        GROUP BY p.Reviewer) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.Reviewer AS Name, p.Status
   FROM Review AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Status) FOR Name IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the help and quick solution.