# SQL Server - Set a Column Name Dynamically From a Column Value

Tags: sql

How to set a column name dynamically from column values?
I see this have [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808230/12096215) for a scenario whit finite number of possible values. How about when the string of values are not exactly known or are too many? How can I dynamically assign the value of [col1] after "AS" in the query below, so that I still get the results achieved in the link above?

`SELECT
id,
MAX(CASE WHEN (col1 like 'nam%') THEN col2 ELSE NULL END) AS [col1],

FROM
yourtable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id`

Having this table:

```
id    col1     col2
----------------------
0      name    ax
0      name2   bx
0      name3   cx
1      name    dx
1      name2   ex
1      name3   fx
```

I tried this:

```
`SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (col1 like 'nam%') THEN col2 ELSE NULL END) AS [col1],

FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id`
```

I was expecting:

```
id   name    name2     name3
0    ax      bx         cx
1    dx      ex         fx
```

But no luck.

Comment: You want "pivoting". Plenty of answers about that in stackoverflow.

Comment: I think you missed part of my question or maybe I wasn't clear, I know how to do the pivoting on this, the question is on the dynamically assignment of the column name.

Comment: when you say "But no luck", what do you mean? does it give an error, or a wrong result, or what? Please show us as much relevant info as you can

Comment: The SQL clauses themselves can only provide static pivoting. If you need dynamic pivoting you'll need to use Dynamic SQL to assemble the query on the fly, according to the existing values in the table.